# insert a variable from name to file and concatenate file

Tags: r

I need to combine set of csv files into one, but I need to keep the variable from the file name.

Example is below

file name: Paris_correlations.csv
data as below:

```
ID A B C
x  2 4 6
y  5 7 9
```

file name: Madrid_correlations.csv
data as below:

```
ID A B C
x  4 6 2
y  1 8 5
```

and I need to combine this into one file - combined.csv

```
ID city A B C
x  Paris 2 4 6
y  Paris 5 7 9
x  Madrid 4 6 2
y  Madrid 1 8 5
```

And I have more than 1000 files like that (there is constant element in names of the files - ***_correlations.csv).

How can I combine this?

Comment: How many rows and columns in each file?

Comment: @rjen 10 columns and different number of rows (sometimes is for example x,y,z; sometimes only x;z - but between 10 to 100)